# Cant see StrictMode details on logcat - Suppressed StrictMode policy violation on screen rotation

Tags: android, supportmapfragment, android-framelayout, android-strictmode

My problem is this, I'm trying to understand the source of this trace:

```
11-06 22:07:36.593 2744-3492/com.spot.spottester W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-06 22:07:36.594 2744-2744/com.spot.spottester W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
```

I got these StrictMode lines appearing on my Android Studio logcat every time I rotate screen from portrait to landscape and viceversa. I dont understand why logcat indicates "Suppressed" because I think StrictMode is activated in my main Activity (the only one)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .build());
```

Additional information: 
I see this strict mode violations when Im working with maps, map fragment on FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.35">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Additional lines of logcat

```
11-07 08:47:39.495 32751-4156/com.spot.spottester I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 15.568MB for 196624-byte allocation

11-07 08:47:40.217 32751-32751/com.spot.spottester I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9877036
```

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: Now fixed as of Google Play Services 10.2.0:

> Good news! The issue where you were seeing "Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation" logs is now fixed in Google Play Services 10.2. The fix in the the Google Play Services APK which is installed on your users devices.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11077

---

ORIGINAL: I have been seeing these "Suppressed StrictMode policy violation" messages in logcat too - using Google Maps fragment.
Even though I am not using StrictMode in my app, the suppression messages still appear.

I think it might be related to this issue fix from Google in October, as I have only noticed it recently:

> This issue is now fixed in the Google Play Services 9.8 release. You
>   should no longer see StrictMode violations from the Android Maps API
>   in the logs, and you should therefore be able to re-enable StrictMode
>   in your Activity.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10170

My thinking is they 'fixed' the big stack trace outputs by writing them as a single 'suppressed' line instead... but they've put it in for non-strict mode apps too.

Comment: Thank you cometfish, I am using 9.8 release and still seeing  Suppressed StrictMode log line, very strange.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Does anyone know how to at least ignore these messages in logcat?

Comment: Still get this in 10.0.x too

Comment: so is this just always going to appear? Virtually every time someone non-android looks at my log they come over and I have to explain that this isn't something to do with me... very tedious

Comment: Looks like this is fixed as of google play services v10.2.0... I'll update my answer.